# Add method to Array object

Tags: php

Привет.
Как изменить поведение стандартного метода PHP для работы с массивами и объектами ,как добавить новый стандартный метод?
Что-то наподобие такого в js

```
 Array.prototype.indexOf = function (vItem) {
        for (var i=0; i < this.length; i++) {
            if (vItem == this[i]) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
    var aColors = new Array("red", "green", "yellow");
    alert(aColors.indexOf("green"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конкретно для этого варианта есть стандартная функция [`array_search()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-search.php).

А, в целом, ничто не мешает создать функцию типа:

```
function func_name(&$array, $value){
    foreach($array as $key=>$val)
        if($val==$value)
            return $key;
    return false;
}
```